# Convert ISO-8601 string date to ORACLE timestamp with timezone datatype

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, rhino, iso8601

I want to convert the below date which is  ISO 8601 Zulu time format .

```
2022-05-05T18:08:13.311Z
```

to the below Oracle timestamp with timezone data type

```
05-MAY-22 06.08.13.311 +00:00
```

Is there any functions or methods we can make use of in Javascript to achieve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of the conversion, i.e., how with the converted date value be used? Also, the Oracle timestamp format shown in the question doesn't appear to match the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081).

Comment: I have changed the format. I am converting this to oracle timestamp format as that data type won't be able to hold the iso format.

Comment: Oracle timestamps don't have any intrinsic human-readable format. If you're ultimately sending the JS string value to the database then you can leave it in ISO format and convert it on the database side with `to_timestamp_tz()` with a matching format mask (or possibly`to_utc_timestamp_tz()`).

Comment: In Oracle, a `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data type that is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format (it is stored in 20 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second, 6 bytes for fractional seconds and 7 bytes for time zone information). What you see is the default format used by the client application to **display** the binary data received from the database and this display format bears no relation to the binary format used by the database for storage.